# How do I generate a unique sequential number in java?

Tags: mysql, mybatis, sequences

I need to create an entity form which has unique identification column in the database and its not a primary key column and I need to display that in the form creation page. I've set this column as UNIQUE and not null. Now whenever I create a new user, employee or any entity I need to generate a sequence number like in this format and display it in the form,

```
ID_001, ID_002 ... ID_00N and so on.

EMP_001, EMP_002 ... EMP_00N and so on.
```

and when the three digit sequence number reaches the max limit of 999. The seqence number should generate the number as four digits until 9999 is reached and the employee code will be like `EMP_1000`. So when I get the last insert id when creating the form, it will not work if more than one user is creating simultaneously and there would be a conflict. I thought about creating a new table like `sequence_generator`. Where I store key-value pair of the the entity-last insert id. So whenver next insert happens I can read from this table and increment by 1 for new sequence numbers.

So How do I best implement this sequence generating which is also Unique in `Java/MySql/Mybatis/Spring`?

Comment: why dont you try using UUIDs ?

Comment: Is a database sequence an option? It might contain holes or even end to be non monotonic according to creation time is caching is in effect, but it does ensure unicity even with distributed servers.

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh UUIDs are lenghty string randomly generated. I want the numbers to be sequential(like 001,002 and so on).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, I need the values to be in a sequence(001,002 and so on). It can skip values but I dont want two users with same sequence number at same time. Instead of random numbers I want a sequence number from the database. If I have two EMP_001 and EMP_002 in database, the next value to be inserted in the db can be EMP_003 or EMP_004. But not `EMP_RANDOM_NUMBER`.

Comment: why do u want the number to be generated in java ? if your primary key is incremental, you could just append EMP_ to it.

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh Because, I need to generate it for a setter method before I put an entry into the database in mybatis.

Comment: No chance to create the sequence in the database and ask the database for the next number when needing it in Java? Of course you can create a sequence generator in java, etc. - but databases tend to have such stuff already, so why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: SELECT MAX(fileid) FROM table would give you the max primary key and you can increment it by 1, when setting in the db.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz In hibernate it can be done with a sequence_table, `@GeneratedValue(generator = "table", strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)` right? But, I'm using mybatis.

Comment: And using selectKey with BEFORE order to add "EMP" to the LAST_INSERT_ID store in the keyproperty and use it as value in the query?

Comment: SelectKey seems a good choice, true. For the sequence itself, it depends on the database, some do already offer some sort of sequence generating.

Comment: you have tagged this question with "java" - what relevance is java here?

Comment: You should certanly use the AUTO_INCREMENT feature for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would create my own sequencing implementation using triggers. I am not very familiar with mysql. So, take my examples as a pseudo-code. Your trigger would look like:

1. Create a table with no auto-increment. Example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
>     ID CHAR(30), NAME CHAR(30)
> )
> ```

2. Create a trigger with the logic to auto-increment your columns. Similar to:

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_SEQUENCE BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     SET @PREPENDED_ZEROS = '';
>     SET @ID_AS_NUMBER = CAST(SUBSTRING(ID,3) AS INT) + 1;
>     IF @ID_AS_NUMBER < 10 THEN
>        SET @PREPENDED_ZEROS = '00';
>     ELSEIF @ID_AS_NUMBER < 100 THEN
>        SET @PREPENDED_ZEROS = '0';
>     END IF;
>     SET NEW.ID = 'EMP_' || @PREPENDED_ZEROS || @ID_AS_NUMBER;
> END;
> ```